# Need to get json output from solr and not the html response

Tags: solr

Need to get json output from solr "/admin/metrics?group=solr.jvm&prefix=os&wt=json" through python 3 but I am getting html. Is there an out of the box python module to get the json response and not the html.

Comment: Have you verified what the response you're getting is? If the URL is the same as what Solr uses in its frontend (you can watch which requests are getting made in your browser's development tools), it should return the same. How are you making the request (include relevant code)?

Comment: What I have indicated above, through browser and code, the response is in html. If you have a solr instance, you can check it easily. I have tried using the html_to_json or html_to_text but it is not working. It actually converts the whole html, with all the html tags. The expected output should be the json response only. Using the "&wt=json" by appending it on the URL is not working.

Comment: The reason why I'm asking is _because when I'm making the same request_ a JSON response is returned. _What_ is the response you're receiving back, and what's the exact request you're making? Simply accessing `http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/metrics?group=solr.jvm&prefix=os` in a browser or by using a plain cURL-request  returns a JSON formatted response (with `Content-Type: application/json`). So _the actual response you're getting might be useful to tell you exactly what is going wrong_. (i.e. is it a 404, does the web interface work, etc.) Which version of Solr are you using?

Comment: It is enclosed in pre tag. Using curl it is also returning html. Same as in browser.

Comment: So what is the actual response (add it to your question)? What is your Solr version? Have you changed your Solr configuration in any way?

Comment: The response is html form.

<form id="samlRedirect" data-refreshParent="true" action="https://accounts.sap.com/saml2/idp/sso" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">

Comment: That seems like you need to pass along an active loginsession - i.e. your instance needs authentication present so you can access it (possibly through a proxy in front of it as indicated by `accounts.sap.com`).